# Need to hash emailed 'verification' URL?

Tags: php, mysql, hash, email-verification

I have a form which collects basic user information. On the subsequent page it asks the user to enter a 'verification' code to ensure they have access to the email account mentioned.

Additionally, in the event somebody accidentally leaves the site altogether before entering their validation code, I will provide a link with a unique $_GET variable so they can verify their email address.

A couple questions:

1. Is there any harm in storing the validation code in plain site (say the code was 12345) next to the customers email address in a database?
2. Is there a need to 'hash' the verification URL $_GET variable? My thought was to simply create a 64 character string, append to the end of a URL and check against a database value (again stored alongside email address).

I would never do the same for user passwords (leave in open un-hashed) but in this case, what is the proper method?

### edit

it seems people like the GUID idea (though I'm not sure how it is more unique than say a 64 character randomly generated string). Does the function below seem sufficient?

```
function getGUID(){
    if (function_exists('com_create_guid')){
        return com_create_guid();
    }else{
        mt_srand((double)microtime()*10000);//optional for php 4.2.0 and up.
        $charid = strtoupper(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)));
        $hyphen = "-";
        $uuid = "{"
            .substr($charid, 0, 8).$hyphen
            .substr($charid, 8, 4).$hyphen
            .substr($charid,12, 4).$hyphen
            .substr($charid,16, 4).$hyphen
            .substr($charid,20,12)
            ."}";
        return $uuid;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the user to type anything in to validate? Isn't clicking the link enough validation?

Comment: @Amir - agreed but persons in our organization think that 'clicking a link' is a pain in the a** and think it is confusing to have a new browser window open up once the user clicks the link (thus having 2 windows for the same site).

Comment: just show all other application in the world to this person where they sign up and then click the link on the email address to validate. :) Feel your pain :)

Comment: @Amir - their example is the situation banks use in which a 5 digit code is emailed or texted to the record on file and manually entered to proceed on a login process.

Comment: Why `$hyphen = chr(45);// "-"`, why not just `$hyphen = "-";`

Comment: @Johan - runs the same effect, the //"-" was just to show what chr(45) is.

Comment: @JM4, I know it does the same thing, it just seems silly in the extreme to use CHR() where you can just use the value itself. Methinks you have been engaged in too many obfuscation contests of late.

Comment: haha perhaps that is true. I'll fix for you ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a GUID and forget about it! You could store it in another table if so desired. No need to hash it.

Comment: If you're extra paranoid, you can also record the time that you generated the UUID and then expire it after say, 15 minutes or so. Require slow users to re-send an new UUID.

Comment: @Karew Most I've encountered expire after 24 hours.

Comment: @Daniel A. White - thanks. Are there any existing PHP functions which accomplish this or just build out in the 8-4-4-4-12 format? In all reality, I don't see how this is easier than creating the 64 character random string and saving in that case?

Comment: @Michael That works too, 15 minutes is probably a little harsh.

Comment: Also - what about the user who wants to simply key in, say, a 5 digit verification code.

Comment: @JM4 There is a [PECL package](http://pecl.php.net/package/uuid) or [MySQL can do it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid). Alternatively, you could steal the UUID functions from the CakePHP or Khoana frameworks.

Comment: @Karew - thanks, I added a function above but since we are in fact using MYSQL, it seems that function may be the simplest?